# Getting error in Haskell when running from external file "variable not in scope"

Tags: haskell

The problem I am facing is running from an external file 
But I am getting the error "Variable not in scope"

I am running on windows and its the most basic program. When I am trying to do this fully by command prompt it is working fine. But when I am trying to do this from an external file it is giving this error

file name: haskell_trial.hs

```
doubleMe x = x + x
```

While running this is the error:

```
Prelude> :l haskell_trial
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( haskell_trial.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> doubleMe 5

<interactive>:6:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: doubleMe :: Integer -> t
```

This is what i get when i simply do it from command prompt:

```
Prelude> doubleme x = x+x
Prelude> doubleme 9
18
```

Comment: are you sure that you have it as `doubleMe` in the file, and not `doubleme`? Haskell is case sensitive.

Comment: yep its as doubleMe

Comment: well something is up, because this should definitely work. Can you edit your question to show the complete contents of `haskell_trial.hs`

Comment: there is just one line there doubleMe x = x + x

Comment: I'm sorry to keep repeating myself, but we need to see an *exact* replica of 1) the file you're loading and 2) your GHCi session. Everything you have said you have done should lead to the function working as expected with no error, so something must be amiss somewhere - until I see the exact details of what you've done I can't guess as to what. We're really into trivial troubleshooting here, like are you definitely loading the correct file (and not a different Haskell file without this function in it)?

Answer (score 0):

It was some setup issue. I installed again and it started working fine